# SSRS: External image in tablix cell

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

My data set contains a column named `IconUri` that contains a full HTTP address to an image located on a web server. This data set is bound to a tablix, and I'd like to display the image in a cell.

1) I've tried to drag an image into the cell, but I can't use expressions as the image itself isn't aware of its parent's (the tablix) data set.

2) I've also tried to apply the image as a cell background, and while this certainly displays the image, it repeats it in horizontal and vertical direction, which is undesirable. The cell shall contain only one copy of the image.

3) I've tried to create a rectangle in the cell, but it will scale to the cell itself and thus the same effect as above.

Is there a way in which this might be done? I'm even open to performing some XML hacking if this is what is necessary. Thank you!

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: No, I didn't! I solved the problem though by manually editing the XML. Once I did this, it seems to solve everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by examining the XML code that the editor created for the image, and I moved the relevant tag inside the tablix cell and assigned the appropriate bindings. When I re-opened the editor again, everything fell into place: the image recognizes the data source and compiling as well as rendering works flawelessly.

Answer (score 3):

From the toolbox drag an image into your the cell of your tablix:

[image]

Then right click on the newly added image in the cell and select Image Properties:

[image]

Change the image source to External and then pick the dataset field that contains your product URL:

[image]

If you get the dreaded red cross instead of an image when you run the report, triple check that the URL actually does point at a publicly available image.

If your using a file from the file system rather than an image hosted at a url, you need to ensure the file path is [in the form of "file:///C:/RDLCTest/TestImage.png"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16890787/1879019).

If your also displaying the report in the ReportViewer control you will need to turn on [`EnableExternalImages`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.enableexternalimages.aspx) for the report [in code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48f25025-0e76-4107-92a5-a61ac631bceb/the-enableexternalimages-property-has-not-been-set-for-this-report-vs2015?forum=sqlreportingservices), but that isn't needed if your just outputting the report to say a PDF and downloading it

Answer (score 1):

Use Image and in the image properties set the value to something like this
= Code.ConvertTotWebUrl(First(Fields!Logo.Value, "dsOrder"))