# Display Image on Report.rdlc file from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to show image on report.rdlc file on image control. I upload the image into project folder and path of image in to database table.!
the Image Property is set to External

How i can do this?

Comment: hi.. On Report1.rdlc file

Comment: Reference this > http://stackoverflow.com/a/16890787/1427849

Comment: my path is stored in database table. "C:\Users\Vi(ky\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\testdemo\testdemo\ImageStore\My_Life_My_Style.jpg" Please explain

Comment: try with it `new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Vi(ky\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\testdemo\testdemo\ImageStore\My_Life_My_Style.jpg").Directory.Name` !

Answer (score 0):

your path should be

```
http://yourdomain/imagename.jpg
```

In rdlc you should provide path of server where image is uploaded. and if you want to show a static image try embedded image type instead.